# Ordering transaction search results when using the NetSuite PHP SDK

Tags: php, netsuite

I have some simple code that searches NetSuite for a customers orders. The orders are returned oldest first. Is there an easy way to return them ordered by newest first? I've tried looking through the inners of the Ryan Winchester SDK we're using plus made lots of google searches but but surprisingly haven't found anything useful

Here's the code

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Product;

use App\Component\NetSuite\ServiceFactoryInterface;
use NetSuite\Classes\CustomerSearchBasic;
use NetSuite\Classes\RecordRef;
use NetSuite\Classes\SearchEnumMultiSelectField;
use NetSuite\Classes\SearchMultiSelectField;
use NetSuite\Classes\SearchRequest;
use NetSuite\Classes\TransactionSearch;
use NetSuite\Classes\TransactionSearchBasic;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class QuickTest
{
    private ServiceFactoryInterface $netSuiteServiceFactory;

    public function __construct(ServiceFactoryInterface $netSuiteServiceFactory) {
        $this->netSuiteServiceFactory = $netSuiteServiceFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @Route(path="benstest")
     */
    public function bensTest()
    {
        $customerSearchBasic = new CustomerSearchBasic();

        $searchValue = new RecordRef();
        // @phpstan-ignore-next-line
        $searchValue->type = 'customer';
        $searchValue->internalId = (string) '14835';

        $searchMultiSelectField = new SearchMultiSelectField();
        setFields($searchMultiSelectField, ['operator' => 'anyOf', 'searchValue' => $searchValue]);
        $customerSearchBasic->internalId = $searchMultiSelectField;

        $transactionSearchBasic = new TransactionSearchBasic();

        $searchMultiSelectEnumField = new SearchEnumMultiSelectField();
        setFields($searchMultiSelectEnumField, ['operator' => 'anyOf', 'searchValue' => "_salesOrder"]);

        $transactionSearchBasic->type = $searchMultiSelectEnumField;
        $transactionSearch = new TransactionSearch();
        $transactionSearch->basic = $transactionSearchBasic;
        $transactionSearch->customerJoin = $customerSearchBasic;

        $request = new SearchRequest();
        $request->searchRecord = $transactionSearch;

        $nsService = $this->netSuiteServiceFactory->getNetSuiteService();

        $nsService->setSearchPreferences(false, 10);
        $response = $nsService->search($request);

        dd($response);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to do this on the fly as part of your search. The API doesn't appear to have any orderBy/sortBy type controls, only result page size. It is looking to me like to accomplish this, you'll need to create a custom search in NetSuite, then use a `TransactionSearchAdvanced` object, setting the `$savedSearchScriptId` (which appears to expect the 'ID' field from the interface) accordingly. Attach a `TransactionSearch` to it as the `$criteria` property and you should be on your way.